# Kivy: add pop-up widget on button press

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, widget

I'm new to kivy and just trying to understand how it works.

Here's my question: how to set size parameters for boxlayout into OntopLabel widget?

My goal is to throw a pop-up widget on button press, where output from the terminal will be printed.

Maybe, I will have to use a different layout for this purpose?

Current code:

main.py

```
class TestWidget(Widget):
    def add_my_label(self):
        lbl = OntopLabel()
        self.add_widget(lbl)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
TestWidget:
<TestWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        orientation:'vertical'
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            text: 'Press'
            on_press: root.add_my_label()
```

ontop_label.py

```
class OntopLabel(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(rgba=(kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex("#6C5B7B"))[:3] + [.5])
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)
            
        lbl = Label(text='Hi', size_hint=(1, 1), pos_hint={"center_x": .5})
        self.add_widget(lbl)
```

Output I get after pressing a button:

[On button press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcQdl.png)

Comment: The main issue is that you are using `Widget` as a container for other widgets. The `Widget` class is not designed to be a useful container, and does not handle things like `size_hint`, `pos_hint`, ... That means that the `OntopLabel` will keep its default `size` and `position` (`(100,100)` and `(0,0)`). Consider using a `Layout` class as the base for your `TestWidget`.

Comment: Makes sense.
The way I was doing it is wrong, I just found the solution here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzUTZj31AfM&list=PLCC34OHNcOtpz7PJQ7Tv7hqFBP_xDDjqg&index=30&ab_channel=Codemy.com